# Magento 2.3 ElasticSearch Suite 1.9 Product Filter Not Showing Simple Products when selecting a colour. It will only show configurable ones

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, elasticsearch

I'm working on a Magento 2.3.6 site which Catalog / Search Engine setup for ElasticSearch Suite 1.9.

The products' visibility are setup this way:
Simple products: Search
Configurable products: Search, Catalog

On the frontend when selecting a filter, eg a colour, the results are not showing simple products which matches the filter. It will only display configurable ones.

I don't want the simple products to show in the catalog, but the only way ElasticSearch Suite filter bar will display the variations will be if their visibility is set to Catalog or "Catalog, Search".

While debugging the elasticsearch query, I can see that somehow visibility is being set twice

```
{"size":24,"sort":[{"cf_new":{"order":"desc","missing":"_first","unmapped_type":"keyword"}},{"name.sortable":{"order":"ASC","missing":"_first","unmapped_type":"keyword"}},{"_score":{"order":"asc"}},{"entity_id":{"order":"asc","missing":"_last","unmapped_type":"keyword"}}],"from":0,"query":{"constant_score":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"category","score_mode":"none","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must_not":[{"term":{"category.is_virtual":{"value":true,"boost":1}}}],"boost":1}},{"terms":{"category.category_id":["3"],"boost":1}}],"must_not":[],"should":[],"boost":1}},"boost":1}},{"term":{"stock.is_in_stock":{"value":true,"boost":1}}},{"terms":{"visibility":[2,4],"boost":1}},{"bool":{"must_not":[{"nested":{"path":"category","score_mode":"none","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.category_id":{"value":3,"boost":1}}},{"term":{"category.is_blacklisted":{"value":true,"boost":1}}}],"must_not":[],"should":[],"boost":1}},"boost":1}}],"boost":1}},{"terms":{"visibility":[3,4],"boost":1}}],"must_not":[],"should":[],"boost":1}},"boost":1}},"post_filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"attribute_set_id":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"attribute_set_id":{"terms":{"field":"attribute_set_id","size":100000,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}},"categories":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"categories":{"filters":{"filters":{"9":{"nested":{"path":"category","score_mode":"none","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must_not":[{"term":{"category.is_virtual":{"value":true,"boost":1}}}],"boost":1}},{"terms":{"category.category_id":["9"],"boost":1}}],"must_not":[],"should":[],"boost":1}},"boost":1}},"10":{"nested":{"path":"category","score_mode":"none","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must_not":[{"term":{"category.is_virtual":{"value":true,"boost":1}}}],"boost":1}},{"terms":{"category.category_id":["10"],"boost":1}}],"must_not":[],"should":[],"boost":1}},"boost":1}},"30":{"nested":{"path":"category","score_mode":"none","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must_not":[{"term":{"category.is_virtual":{"value":true,"boost":1}}}],"boost":1}},{"terms":{"category.category_id":["30"],"boost":1}}],"must_not":[],"should":[],"boost":1}},"boost":1}}}}}}},"option_text_cf_category":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"option_text_cf_category":{"terms":{"field":"option_text_cf_category.untouched","size":10,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}},"option_text_cf_search_cat":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"option_text_cf_search_cat":{"terms":{"field":"option_text_cf_search_cat.untouched","size":10,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}},"option_text_cf_materials_filter":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"option_text_cf_materials_filter":{"terms":{"field":"option_text_cf_materials_filter.untouched","size":10,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}},"option_text_cf_design":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"option_text_cf_design":{"terms":{"field":"option_text_cf_design.untouched","size":10,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}},"option_text_cf_technique_filter":{"filter":{"terms":{"option_text_cf_colour.untouched":["Black"],"boost":1}},"aggregations":{"option_text_cf_technique_filter":{"terms":{"field":"option_text_cf_technique_filter.untouched","size":10,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}},"option_text_cf_colour":{"terms":{"field":"option_text_cf_colour.untouched","size":100000,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}},"track_total_hits":true}
```

[image]

Does anyone know why this could be happening? I've reindexed the DB so it's not a problem with that. If I change a Simple product Visibility from Search to Catalog, that simple product it will start being displayed when filtering by any of the filterable attributes.

Comment: Did you check different configuration scopes and checked all the values? like in "All Store Views", in your store view etc?

Comment: Hi @JohnFonseka , Which values are you talking about? If I focus on one product in particular, which has colour black and I look at it on the different stores, the value both for the filterable attribute colour and for the visibility is always there same. If you mean any other value, please clarify so I can give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: I meant what you were saying. Because you mentioned 2 values there for visibility I thought there can be different values saved for different store views.

Comment: ah right, unfortunately the visibility value is the same for all different stores. thx anyway